# RODBC - connection string add username and password

Tags: r, rodbc

I want to connect though a connection string to a SQL server.

```
library(RODBC)
server <- "servername"
database<- "db_name"
username <- "MyId"
password <- "MyPassword"
connectionString <- paste0("Driver={SQL Server};server=",server,";database=",database,";trusted_connection=yes;")
channel <-  odbcDriverConnect(connection=connectionString)
```

But I'm not sure how to add the details for username and password. The documentation for the connectionString seems a little bit vague.

Anyone?

Comment: do you have a missing `"` on 5th line in your code as well ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes, my bad. Through, question is really about how to include properly the two strings (username and password) in the connection string. So the typo is not really essential.

Comment: How about this `paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server}; server=",server,"; database=",db_name,"; uid=",username,"; pwd=",MyPassword, "; trusted_connection=yes;", sep="")`

Comment: @suchait it fails. I get [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user....

Comment: I know the credential works because I can login with the same username/pass on SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Try it once without trusted_connection part.

Comment: Promotheus it's not well documented in the `R` doc because it's not an R issue, check this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and go to the secion `Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver` and you'll find `Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: @suchait yes, it solved it. Thank you.

Comment: @suchait you should post as an answer

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add username and password in a connection string this way:

```
connectionString <- paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server}; server=",server,"; database=",db_name,"; uid=",username,"; pwd=",MyPassword, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this simpler by using `glue`, then you can skip the awkward `paste0` step.

```
library(glue)
library(RODBC)

server <- "servername"
database<- "db_name"
username <- "MyId"
password <- "MyPassword"

channel <- odbcDriverConnect(glue("driver=SQL Server; 
                                   server={server}; 
                                   database={database}; 
                                   uid={username}; 
                                   pwd={password};"))
```